# Prob. 3 a) Sec. 3.3 in Kreyszig "introductory Functional Analysis with Applications"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Can someone help me please

Show that the vector space X of all real-valued continuous functions on [-1,1] is the direct sum of the set of all even continuous functions and the set of all odd continuous functions on [-1, 1].

Comment: Hint: For any $f$, let $O_f$ be its odd part and $E_f$ be its even part. Then $f(x)=E_f(x)+O_f(x)$ while $f(-x)=E_f(-x)+O_f(-x)=E_f(x)-O_f(x)$. What's the function that is both odd and even?

Comment: Try using some algebra to show that any such function $f$ can be written as a sum of an even function and an odd function. The even function and odd function will both be defined in terms of $f$. (Think about the reflection of $f$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x)={1\over2}((f(x)+f(-x)))+{1\over 2}(f(x)-f(-x)))$.

$g(x)={1\over2}((f(x)+f(-x)))$

$h(x)={1\over2}((f(x)-f(-x)))$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=\{f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} | f \text{ is even}\}$ and $O=\{f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} | f \text{ is odd}\}$. In order to show that $X$ is the direct sum of $E$ and $O$. You need to show two things :

- $X=E+O$ : Let $f \in X$, let $f_1(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ and $f_2(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$. We have $f_1(-x)=\frac{f(-x)-f(-(-x))}{2}=\frac{f(-x)-f(x)}{2}=-f_1(x)$, so $f_1$ is odd, $f_1 \in O$. And $f_2(-x)=\frac{f(-x)+f(-(-x))}{2}=\frac{f(-x)+f(x)}{2}=f_2(x)$, so $f_2$ is even, $f_2 \in E$. Finally $f_1(x)+f_2(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}=f(x)$. So $f=f_1+f_2$. We proved that each element of $X$ can be decomposed as a sum of an element of $O$ and an element of $E$. We proved $X=E+O$.
- $E\cap O=\{0\} $ : Let $f\in E \cap O$. $\forall x \in [-1,1], f(x)=f(-x)=-f(x)$ so $\forall x \in [-1,1], f(x)=0$, so $f=0$. So we proved that $E\cap O=\{0\} $.

Since the two conditions are verified, we have : $X=E\oplus O$.

Answer (score 0):

I did so

Be $X = P \cap I$ with $P = pair$ and $I= odd$ in [-1,1]

$f \in X, -f \in X$ exist $f(t)$ any $t \in [-1,1]$ such that $f(-t)$

Thus $f(t)= \dfrac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}+\dfrac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2}$

Be $ z \in P \cap I$, then $z(t)=z(-t)=-z(-t)$, any $t \in [-1,1]  $.

So, $z = 0$

Is correct?